# How to Store value for EditText in Session

Tags: android

In **Cart** Activity, i am allowing user to **Edit Quantity** of an item, and also *getting changes in Total amount* as user does **change in Quantity**, but here i am facing a small problem, whenever i do click on back button, it will reset my quantity, why?

please see below screen shot:

![enter image description here][1]

*For an example, in above screen i have edited Quantity for my product Veggie from 1 to 15 and also getting change in Total, but the problem is once i do click on back button, then i will get again value for Quantity 1 not 15, which i have entered earlier*

**Please tell me how can i control on this ?**

*CartAdapter.java:*

```
    if(cost.getText().length() > 0)
    {
        try
        {
           itemamount = Double.parseDouble(cost.getText().toString());
           Log.d("ProductInformationActivity", "ItemAmount :: " + itemamount);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            itemamount=0.00;
            Log.d("ProductInformationActivity", "NumberFormatException :: " + e);
        }
    }

    qty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

            if (!qty.getText().toString().equals("")
                    || !qty.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                // accept quantity by user
                itemquantity = Integer.parseInt(qty.getText()
                        .toString());

                total.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.#").format(itemamount*itemquantity));

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        });

    return vi;      
}       
  }
```

Comment: You have to used startActivityForResult and get data back into onActivityResult.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you save your values and populate them in your `onCreate()`?  You can use any of three mechanisms to get what you want.

1. Shared Preferences
2. SQLite DB
3. Application

Answer (score 0):

using `SQLite DB` looks like the best option considering the functionality you require...

Answer (score -1):

If you are already storing the value and just want to control how the back button works you could use this in your cart activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //Your code
        return true; // so the super method doesn't get called
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```